# Excluding a column from an inner join in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I am trying to exclude a column (`county`) that is shared by both table so I can do a `LEFT JOIN` in a query. This is what I thought would work but there seems to be some issues (below produces the `ERROR: syntax error at or near "LEFT"`). What can I do to get this work?

```
CREATE TABLE levee_prioritization.svi_justice_communities_joined AS
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = 'levee_prioritization'
   AND table_name = 'svi2018_us_tract') AS allColumns 
   WHERE allColumns.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('county'))
LEFT JOIN levee_prioritization.justice40_communities b ON (a.fips = 
LPAD(round(b.geoid_tract)::text, 11));
```

Comment: If you expect the inner select to return the value of the table's column you are mistaken. It only returns the **name** of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the view name for inner select:

```
CREATE TABLE levee_prioritization.svi_justice_communities_joined AS
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = 'levee_prioritization'
   AND table_name = 'svi2018_us_tract') AS allColumns 
   WHERE allColumns.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('county')) a
LEFT JOIN levee_prioritization.justice40_communities b 
ON (a.fips = LPAD(round(b.geoid_tract)::text, 11));
```

Comment: I am getting a.fips does not exist. I does exist, so something is off.

Comment: @gwydion93 because you're selecting only `column_name` in the inner query. It's an issue with your query